# what expected have getExternalStorageDirectory() of path_provider dependency?

Tags: flutter

I have an application that i develop with flutter and i need to acces local storage. what is expected return of that code?

i use the package path_provider:^1.2.2

```dart
var directory=await getExternalStorageDirectory();
print(directory.path)
```

I obtains: **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapplication.application/files**

while i expect to have **/storage/emulated/0/**.

I want to know if is not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove the .getAbsolutePath() and it will be fine. Environment.getExternalStoreDirectory() will give you the path to wherever the manufacture has set its external storage.**
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/String/substring.html for trimming path as you need...

Comment: i have contructed path by using the uri path segments. but i afraid that every android systemt don't have the same structure.

Comment: you want to access device storage or local storage for storing data temporarily?

Comment: to acces device storage i think. i have created folder in the folder where whatsapp, downloads, dcim are located.

Comment: Remove the .getExternalStorageDirectory() and it will be fine. Environment.getExternalStoreDirectory() will give you the path to wherever the manufacture has set its external storage.

Comment: i use vscode and when i try to use 'Environment' the class is unrecognize. Is there some packge to import before use Environmment?

Comment: maybe it's only useful for native java not working in flutter I think, you can go for segments and will reply if i found anything new for you..

Answer (score 2):

another solution is to do like that

```
Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
List<String> segment = directory.uri.pathSegments;
String rootPath = "/" + segment[0] + "/" + segment[1] + "/" + segment[2];
print(rootPath);
```

and you obtains /storage/emulated/0