# How save file in DOWNLOAD folder

Tags: flutter

i am try save a file from internet in folder download. By i only can if manualy use '/sdcard/download/' (in Android, i don't now how works in iOS).

I am using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider), but when use de getExternalStorageDirectories(type: StorageDirectory.downloads) he return 'storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.nameapp/files/Download' and not '/sdcard/download/'.

in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800057/what-expected-have-getexternalstoragedirectory-of-path-provider-dependency) i am recommended use a substring, but it looks wrong....

Exist other plugin for this or should i really use '/sdcard/download/' in my code?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995621/how-to-download-a-file-and-store-it-in-downloads-folder-using-flutter ?

Comment: No... This is my question. Should i really use the absolute path '/sdcard/download/' ? If the path chance? And iOS? Should use absolute path too?

Comment: no idea about ios; also there is no guarantee that an external sdcard is present.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559351/downloads-path-provider-os-error-permission-denied-errno-13 ?