# downloads_path_provider — OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13

Tags: flutter

I use `downloads_path_provider` package to write to download directory.
I set up it as it was recomended 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to project `AndroidManifest.xml`

But when I try to write I get this error
`E/flutter (26091): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/secure-strorage-backup.txt' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)`

here is the code

```
  final file = _localFile;
  file.writeAsString('1234  5678\n');
  file.writeAsString('1234  5678\n');

  File get _localFile {
    final path = _downloadsDirectory.path;
    return File('$path/secure-strorage-backup.txt');
  }
```

How can I write to the downloads folder?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.user.myappname">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Secure Storage"
        ...
```

here is how I get downloadsDirectory

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDownloadsDirectoryState();
  }

  Future<void> initDownloadsDirectoryState() async {
    Directory downloadsDirectory;
    try {
      downloadsDirectory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
    } on PlatformException {
      print('Could not get the downloads directory');
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _downloadsDirectory = downloadsDirectory;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571167/9142279) answer, you will also need to ask your user explicitly for permission to use external storage,you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_permissions) package for that

Update:

[this](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package turns to be better and has a better score,you can use it like this:

```
                  await Permission.storage.request();
                  Directory downloadsDirectory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
                  final String path = downloadsDirectory.path;
                  final File file = File('$path/secure-strorage-backup.txt');
                  await file.writeAsString('1234  5678\n');
                  await file.writeAsString('1234  5678\n');
                  print(await file.readAsString());
```

Comment: When I made it there are new error arrived. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
`Execution failed for task ':simple_permissions:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.` and `* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'downloads_path_provider'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`

Comment: just use the other package, the first one looks like it has been deprecated by its original creator, I tried the second one and it works

Comment: Great! What if I need to write to the SD card instead?

Comment: well that is another question that you can post , and you can mark this question as accepted as it solved you problem :)

Answer (score 1):

**After long Research i find this Solution and it will work on all Android 10+**

Just change **await Permission.storage.request()** to **await     Permission.manageExternalStorage.request()** in your Permission Handler or Requester class.

Because this change will give you full access to Media Storage excluding Restricted Storage.

Detail Example:

First Create a method.

```
Future<AppPermissionStatus> askForPhotoGalleryPermission(
  BuildContext context) async {
var status = Platform.isIOS
    ? await Permission.photos.request()
    : await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request(); 
AppPermissionStatus permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.NotAvailable;

if (status.isGranted) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.Granted;
  return permissionStatus;
} else if (status.isDenied) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.Denied;
  return permissionStatus;
} else if (status.isRestricted) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.Restricted;
  return permissionStatus;
} else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.PermanentlyDenied;
}
return permissionStatus;
}
```

How to call this Method.

```
 void getRequiredPermission(BuildContext context) async {
 AppPermissionStatus permissionStatus =
    await AppPermission().askForPhotoGalleryPermission(context);
  setState(() {
  if (permissionStatus == AppPermissionStatus.Granted) {
    hasPermission = true;
  } else if (permissionStatus == AppPermissionStatus.PermanentlyDenied) {
    hasPermission = false;
  } else {
    hasPermission = false;
  }
});
}
```