# Can't overwrite a file in Download folder on Android 11 and above

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following error *only on Android 11 and above.*

Steps to reproduce:

1. Save a file to `'/storage/emulated/0/Download/fileName.pdf'`
2. Uninstall the app and install it again.
3. Save a file to the same path.

Error:

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/fileName.pdf' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

If I try to delete the file:

```
 PathNotFoundException: Cannot delete file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/fileName.pdf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your app has necessary storage permission after it's been installed again?

Comment: It checks permissions every time before saving a file.

Comment: android 11+ has a different way of managing storage permissions. if files are owned by your app then you can access them like fileName.pdf is saved by your App so you can access and use it but after deleting your app the file is not owned by your app and as treated as you are trying to access a random file from the mobile folder.  you can add MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for permission if you haven't which is used to access all the file. or you can save file in App directory but it will be deleted when app is uninstalled,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not an option because Play Store would reject the app, they have strict rules regarding types of apps that can use that. I can't have file in the app directory because the client wants it to be accessible in Download folder. I have to workaround I guess - ditch the overwriting and give the file unique name.

Answer (score 0):

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in `application` in Manifest file.

Can you try this?

Comment: Already have this, no difference

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used the solution on stackoverflow here: [downloads_path_provider — OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559351/downloads-path-provider-os-error-permission-denied-errno-13)

The accepted answer plus the modification posted by Ramkesh Yadav worked for me.
It does require the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission though, so might not work for you.  Posting here in case others with this issue (like me) land on this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not an option because Play Store would reject the app, they have strict rules regarding types of apps that can use that. I can't have file in the app directory because the client wants it to be accessible in Download folder. I have to workaround I guess - ditch the overwriting and give the file unique name.